# Filtering by UUID in Django Admin

Tags: django

I have the following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Models):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, db_index=True, editable=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

In my django admin, I have the following search_fields:

`search_fields = ["uuid__exact", "name"]`

This should translate to the following query:

`MyModel.objects.filter(Q(uuid__exact=query) | Q(name__icontains=query))`

However, running that query throws the following error:

`ValidationError: ['“test name” is not a valid UUID.']`

How do I prevent the uuid portion of the query from throwing a ValidationError? I want to be able to search my model by either the uuid or the name field in the django admin.

Answer (score 1):

Since `test name` is not a valid `uuid`. So you can check your `query` if it is a valid `uuid` or not before using it in `filter`

You can use `try-except` and if `ValueError` occurs then filter by only `name` as

```
import uuid
from django.db.models import Q

filtered_data = None
try:
    uuid = uuid.UUID(query)
    filtered_data  = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(uuid__exact=query) | Q(name__icontains=query))
except ValueError:
    filtered_data  = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
```

Or append `Q` objects as

```
import uuid
from django.db.models import Q

valid_query = Q(name__icontains=query)
try:
    uuid = uuid.UUID(query)
    valid_query |= Q(uuid)
except ValueError:
    pass

MyModel.objects.filter(valid_query)
```

Comment: Sounds like custom query logic is the only way to accomplish this. Luckily, there's a django admin function for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results

Comment: Didn't it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help:

```
class Cast(Func):
function = "CAST"
template = "%(function)s(%(expressions)s AS varchar)"
Group.objects.annotate(sid=Cast(id)).filter(sid__startswith='000')
```

I'm not sure if [UUIDFields](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27227#comment:7) are searchable. One you could do this would be to have a property or an annotated field in your model that contains the string representation of the UUID.

Comment: I'm asking moreso how to prevent the validationerror on a mismatch so that the name portion of the query will be run. I'm using `uuid__exact` for exact matching but I'd like the rest of the query to run if the uuid doesn't match.

Comment: @swinters I'm not sure how to help you in that case, I'm not very experienced in UUIDs, possibly assign one to a variable and check the variable for what you want, if it does not equal that then you can signal the query to continue running?